# modify object work, but won't do anything with img modification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, backend

i have this function :

```
exports.modifySauce = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.sauce)
  const sauceObject = req.file ?
    {
      ...JSON.parse(req.body.sauce),
      imageUrl: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`
     } : { ...req.body};
     Sauce.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { ...sauceObject, _id: req.params.id })
        .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: 'Sauce modifié !'}))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
  };
```

and when i use it, i can modify everything except when i modify the image, it literally do nothing ...

the console.log(req.body.sauce) return undefined when i change the image

What can i do ?

Thanks in advance and here is my project : https://github.com/Nayrod4/Projet-6 if it can help

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the answer was in the routes/sauces.js

i just forget to put multer at :

```
router.put('/:id', auth, sauceCtrl.modifySauce);
```

now like this

```
router.put('/:id', auth, multer, sauceCtrl.modifySauce);
```

aaaaand voila !